# Android Google Maps searching for places

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to Android development and I wanted to know about using the Google Maps API. What I am trying to accomplish is given the user a list of places defined here in Google Places API (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) table 1 only. When the user picks a supported type, I want to be able to get a list of all the corresponding places as an arraylist. For example, if I picked Hospital, I want to get a list of all closeby hospitals. I am not sure how to go about doing this. Can someone point me in the right direction? Any tutorials? Where can I start?

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [Google Places API Tutorial](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html)